# Data visualization using python

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to know what would be the name of the graph attached under and also what would be the best way to code this using python. I know I have to use networkx, this is what I would do normally but it is not quite the same as I pictured.

[Image I would like to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOBhk.png)

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx 

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('DEP A', resources = ['Accounting'], )
G.add_node('DEP B', resources = ['Economics'] )
G.add_node('DEP C', resources = ['Finance'] )

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

node_sizes = [len(G.nodes[n]['resources'])*200 for n in G.nodes()]`
```

Comment: Note on the graph image where it says `pygal chaco  pyQTgraph`, those might be good places to start